# nginx ssl basic setup

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, configuration

Im relatively new to the server side and have very little idea about configuration so please excuse me if the question seems really basic

I have a nginx+uwsgi server up and running an i would like to configure it for https

```
server {
 ssl on;
 listen 443 ;
 allow all;
 server_name example.com;
 ssl_certificate     sslWork/anotherKey/server.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key sslWork/anotherKey/server.key;
 ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5; 

 # Django admin media.
 location /media/admin/ {
   alias lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/;
 }
 # Your project's static media.
 location /media/ {
   alias PROJECT_ROOT/media/;
 }

 # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.

 location /ai {
   uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8807;
   include     uwsgi_params;
  }

 location /trial {
  uwsgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8817;
  include     uwsgi_params;
 }
}
```

This is what the configuration looks like .. where anotherKey/* are self generated certificates

This is of course just the ssl part of the configuration if anything else is needed i could add it to the question also ..
How i have generated the certificate .. does that matter .. ?
Right now im getting a 'Web page is not available'

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue apparently was that i had not opened the 443 port on the instance .. 
whoops :)